# AndroidManifest.xml file missing! Why am I getting this?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest, apk, android-sdk-tools

I updated my android folders from SDK manager and I created a new android project.Then, I am getting such an error which is

```
 Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon-google_apis-google-19-1': File not found: manifest.ini
 [2014-03-08 17:14:08 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon-google_apis-google-19-1': File not found:    manifest.ini
 [2014-03-08 17:14:22 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 [2014-03-08 17:14:22 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
 [2014-03-08 17:22:20 - 5Food] AndroidManifest.xml file missing!
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse ADT try this: go to Help -> Install new software and select Android repository. Update to the version 22.6 development tools. Uncheck "Contact all update sites during install to find required software". It works for me.